# RavenDB - Loading entity into a different class than it was stored as

Tags: ravendb

An entity was stored as class `A` (which is indicated in the "Raven-Clr-Type" attribute). Is it possible to somehow load/serialize it into a different class?

```
 B entity = session.Load<B>(id)
```

Where `A` and `B` are distinct classes.

Edit: I'm not talking about changing `Raven-Clr-Type` in the database, rather I'm wondering about how to deserialize an entity into a different class than the one specified in `Raven-Clr-Type`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works, but it is not a best practice:

```
  var x = session.Advanced.DocumentStore.DatabaseCommands.Get("stringId/1").ToJson();
  MyType y = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(x.ToString());
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Either use 'patch' and modify the "Raven-Clr-Type" to contain the
       type of class B **-Or-**
2. If classes A & B have the same properties but
       just a different class name than you can remove class A definition
       from your code and RavenDB will load to class B